# What is the correct word for speaking about a regional accent?

Tags: single-word-requests

Some people think the word *akcento* is not suited for regional accent, such as the Italian accent. *Akcento* is about strength and emphasis and not about a particular way of speaking.

Which word should I use?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The word you're looking for is *akĉento*:

> **akĉent/o Λ** Tuto de la artikulaciaj kutimoj de parolanto aŭ grupo de parolantoj (pro trajtoj dialektaj aŭ socilingvaj, influo de denaska lingvo ks), kiu aspektas nenorma en la kadro de difinita lingvo: *havi sudan, kamparan, usonan akĉenton*.

— [PIV](http://vortaro.net/#ak%C4%89ento)

Comment: To help remember which word is which, I remember the phrase "fortaj akĉentoj en esperanto estas aĉaj". both _aĉa_ and _akĉento_ have the _ĉ_.

Answer (score 7):

You could also say "regiona prononcmaniero", which is simply "regional manner of pronunciation". "Prononcmaniero" on its own just means "manner of pronunciation", so doesn't necessarily refer to a regional accent, but as far as I understand, it can encompass that meaning.

I don't see "prononcmaniero" in PIV nor in ReVo nor the Lernu dictionary; I do see it in my usual go-to, [Tuja Vortaro](http://www.tujavortaro.net/). I also find 10 instances of it using [Tekstaro de Esperanto](http://tekstaro.com/)--and beyond that all I can say is, the word came to mind because I can tell you anecdotally that I have seen people using it and have often and since long ago used it myself as a synonym for *akĉento* and/or to refer to someone's pronunciation in general whether I am talking about their regional/national accent or just their particular pronuncation of a certain sound or word.

I do agree that *akĉento* is the word you are looking for, but I thought I would bring up this other one too. I couldn't tell you specifically how I learned it, I was fairly young when I learned Esperanto and generally built up my vocabulary through (online) immersion and conversation, so my anecdotal usages might not be proper, but in my experience they are common and I don't usually find people stopping me to ask what I mean. I'd appreciate it if someone else might confirm having seen this word around, I was surprised not to see it in several dictionaries. Perhaps that's because it's a compound word but I would have thought it was common enough to have its own definition.

Comment: I can confirm; I have heard this as well.

Answer (score 7):

The word is *akĉento*. It filled a lexical gap. I have certainly been familiar with it since the 1980s.

Answer (score 1):

While I prefer to keep the words *akcento* and *akĉento* distinct, I don't correct people who say *akcento* where I would say *akĉento*. This usage is well-established in Esperanto. In the *Tekstaro* *akcento* with this meaning is as common as *akĉento*.

- fortan malagrablan voĉon kun hebrea akcento
- eĉ diverslandajn “akcentojn”
- li parolis kun iu fremdlanda akcento.
- La nigraĉaj akcentoj de Deep South Suite

My understanding is that *akĉento* is a relatively recent coinage. I am unable to find it in my 1970 edition of PIV.

My advice: say *akĉento* in this situation, but don't correct people who say *akcento* because they're in good company.

Comment: La signifo de *akĉento* certe ne estas unu el la signifoj de *akcento* en PIV. Do mi nur povas konkludi, ke tia uzo de *akcento* estas erara. Ĉar *akĉento* ankoraŭ ne estis en tiu malnova eldono de PIV, bonvolu doni la signofojn de *akcento* de tiu eldono.

Comment: An alternative explanation is that the definitions in PIV are not complete. The use of *akcento* for a regional accent goes back to the earliest days of Esperanto. If it is an error, it is an error that is, according to what I found in tekstaro.com, at least as common as the "correct" way to say it. To underscore, I agree that *akĉento* is the better choice - however, to call *akcento* an error, is a bit of a stretch.

Comment: That makes sense. However, perhaps it just used to be correct for the lack of a better word. Considering that PIV adopted the word *akĉento* while leaving the definition of *akcento* without this meaning seems to not only indicate that really the word we ought to use is *akĉento*, but moreover that we should not use *akcento* for this meaning. You do have a point though and I'd be interested to see what PIV used to say for *akcento*. Did they actually remove the meaning of *akĉento* from *akcento* or was it never there?